# Is there a way to reset the phone without re-enabling the disabled apps and services?

Tags: root-access, stock-android

My phone's system UI has become laggier and slow lately. I want to reset the phone which is running Android Pie/ One UI and even though OneUI is a hell of a good UI experience it has a mega tonne of bull crap that I disabled through adb. These include a lotta Samsung services (like samsung pass, keyboard and stickers) and it took a lotta work. Is there a way I can reset the phone without re-enabling the apps? I don't care about the settings getting reset. If not, so is there a way I can clear all of the phones *app data* (i am not talking about app cache)? There are hundreds of apps in a phone (including system ones) and I just wanted to know if there was a way I could reset all of them at once through adb or some app that doesn't require root access.

Comment: A little shameless self-promotion, as I just wanted to recommend the `adb` approach as well: my little tool [Adebar](https://codeberg.org/izzy/Adebar) a.o. creates that script for disabled apps. It also creates scripts for backup and restore, plus a nice little device documentation. While resetting without re-enabling the apps is not possible (like washing without getting wet), this automates re-disabling after a reset (like using a towel).

Comment: @izzy thanks. I'll try that

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can clear all of the phones app data (I am not talking about app cache)?

From `adb shell` do:

```
~$ pm list packages | sed 's/^package://' | xargs -I {} pm clear '{}'
```

This will clear all apps's data and cache.

> Is there a way I can reset the phone without re-enabling the apps?

No. But as @[Firelord](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/96277) suggested in comment, create a list of disabled packages with:

```
~$ pm list packages -d | sed 's/^package://' >disabled_pkgs.txt
```

Keep backup of `.txt` file and after factory reset do:

```
~$ cat disabled_pkgs.txt | xargs -I {} pm disable '{}'
```

If you are using multiple profiles, you also need to use `--user` option with package manager.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. You're a life saver